# How to get this type of json with php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, cakephp

I need to get a json like `[8,3,4,5,6,7,15]`.
I'm triyng to get this based on the last 30 days.

```
$a = array();
for ($i=0; $i < 30; $i++) { 
        $tmp_array = array();
        $inicioDia = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('today - '. $i .' days'));
        $fimDia = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime('today - '. $i .' days'));
        $numeroSolicitacao = $this->Solicitation->find('count', array('conditions' => array('data >' => $inicioDia, 'data <' => $fimDia))); // do the query

            array_push($tmp_array, $numeroSolicitacao);
            $a = $tmp_user;
    }

 json_encode($a)
```

This is returning `["Omnes",3]` with this "Omnes" that I don't know, and just one number.
How i get this type of array?

Comment: Try `$a[] = $numeroSolicitacao;` instead of the last two lines in your `for` loop?

Comment: Where are you getting `$tmp_user` from?  You are setting `$tmp_array`, but assigning `$tmp_user` to `a`.

Comment: @Sam This is the answer!!! My problem is solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are aware that you mix arrays ?

Try this

```
<?php

$tmp_array = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $inicioDia = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime('today - ' . $i . ' days'));
    $fimDia = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59', strtotime('today - ' . $i . ' days'));
    $numeroSolicitacao = $this->Solicitation->find('count', array('conditions' => array('data >' => $inicioDia, 'data <' => $fimDia))); // do the query
    array_push($tmp_array, $numeroSolicitacao);
}

json_encode(tmp_array);
```

Comment: Made my comment official, seems that was the problem though (if OP could accept for others).